# Does Layla have some sort of connection to the X777 event?

Tags: fairy-tail

We all know that the dragons apparently disappeared in the year X777. At the same time, Lucy's mother, Layla Heartfilia, died at the age of 29. I don't know the cause of her death, it's just that I know she passed away at the same year.

Layla Heartfilia seemed to be a powerful Celestial mage given that she had three Golden keys (Aquarius, Capricorn, and Cancer; these three are pretty powerful too) and she probably had more than that (Silver keys or something).

It hasn't been mentioned whether Layla died the same day the dragons disappeared, just that it's the same year, or has it? So I was wondering, could she have had some sort of connection with the disappearance of the dragons?

Yes, the truth about the disappearance of the dragons has been revealed and all, but I still think that there's still something behind this.

> Too bad the dragons can't reveal anything anymore.

Comment: There have been theories about this, but this hasn't been covered in the manga yet. So for now your ideas are as good as anyone's.

Comment: Oh okay. I thought I probably missed it and it has already been covered. Thank you, though.

Comment: The answer to this question is **YES**.

As of the current update on Manga, 7th of July X777 is the day that 'Layla Heartfilia' opens the door of the future for the dragons.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't think so**, if you take a look at the [Fairy Tail](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) timeline you see that for some events there is no exact date known.

According to the timeline, these events happened somewhere in the year X777:

- [Romeo Conbolt](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Romeo_Conbolt) is born.
- [Lector](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Lector) is born.
- Layla dies of an unknown illness.

Therefore we can assume that the aforementioned events did not happen on July 7.

Underneath that you see the events of July 7 X777,

- All dragons disappeared on 7 July.
- Natsu is found by Makarov and invited to join Fairy Tail.
- Mystogan left Edolas through an Anima portal and enters Earth Land.
- [Natsu Dragneel](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Natsu_Dragneel), [Gajeel Redfox](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Gajeel_Redfox), and [Wendy Marvell](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Wendy_Marvell)'s Dragon parents leave them.

I think there is a bigger chance it had to do something with Mystogan coming to Earthland.

Comment: Maybe its time to update this answer with the new shocking reveal that she was involved.

Comment: @Ryan feel free to edit.